# avoid input built-in to read stdin before execute it

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I detect that input builtin capture everything from stdin even before execute it. For example:

```
import time

for n in range(5):
    time.sleep(1)
    # write now something, during the loop

example = input('input something: ')
print("you have written {}".format(example))
```

Trying to flush stdin with sys module before capture input don't work, because if you press "ENTER", for example, this is captured anyway:

```
import time, sys

for n in range(5):
    time.sleep(1)
    # write now something, during the loop

sys.stdin.flush()
example = input('input something: ')
print("you have written {}".format(example))
```

How I can avoid this behaviour and only start to capture the stdin when "input" statement is executed?

Answer (score 0):

One way is the [termios module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/termios.html) (POSIX only):

```
import time, termios, sys

for n in range(5):
    time.sleep(1)
    # write now something, during the loop

termios.tcflush(sys.stdin, termios.TCIOFLUSH)
example = input('input something: ')
print("you have written {}".format(example))
```